# Magento - find the current user is seller or not using If condition

Tags: php, magento

I am setting up an eCommerce store based on Magento. I need to make it so that the user log in functionality is two fold; one for buyers, and one for sellers.

if he/her is a seller then I want to set Some Special functionalities , else for buyer no need.

i'm using Magento CE1.7.0.2

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento providing customer groups functionality.

So you create two customer groups **(seller and buyer)** so on the depending on which customer logged in you place an if condition and get your resulted form displayed.

hope this will sure help you.

For more information about the `customer's entity id, website id, email, etc`. you can use getCustomer function. The following code shows what you can get from it:-

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r(Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getData()); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'm very new to this technology can you please explain in detail

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_6#creating_customer_groups just refer

Comment: in my magento for the both user its taking 'General' group

Comment: but i have one table name " ms_entity_userdata "  here its storing only seller information like firstname,lastname,EmailId,mageuserid,wantpartner,...etc i think these fields are useful to get exact sellers

Comment: yes you can differentiate users with help you this.i would be glad, if you accept my answer so some one can have some issue in future so they utilize our thread.